# Nginx: how to add a rewrite rule to redirect all the requests for a file type?

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I would like to write a rewrite rule for Nginx to redirect any requests for javascript file to a specific JS file. For example 'http://example.com/path1/path2/sample.js?a=1&b=2' should be redirected to 'http://example.com/myjavascript.js'. So I added this rule to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com config file:

```
rewrite .*\.js.* myjavascript.js last;
```

so any URL containing .js should be replaced by myjavascript.js. But when I try  the URL 'http://example.com/path1/path2/sample.js?a=1&b=2', it fails (404). However, the strange thing is that if I replace the js file with an HTML file, such :

```
rewrite .*\.js.* /hello.html last;
```

It redirects it correctly. myjavascript.js is in the same folder as hello.html, but it does not redirect it to this path correctly.

Can you please give me some idea of why it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the missing '/' before the javascript file name, so the correct one should be :

```
rewrite .*\.js.* /myjavascript.js last;
```